# How to get faster fillna/grouping/transform in my function?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

Can u help me please.
I wrote a function to replace missing values ​​in a month, year or the entire column with a specific value (max, mean, min, median), but it works too slowly. How can you speed it up?
When solving a problem, it is forbidden to use the loop and condition operators of the Python language to process the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def fillna_date(data, function = 'mean'):
    d = data.copy()
    d.index = pd.to_datetime(d.index)
    d_m = d.groupby([d.index.year, d.index.month]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.apply(function)))
    ddd = d.fillna(d_m)
    d_y = d.groupby(d.index.year).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.apply(function)))
    ddd = ddd.fillna(d_y)
    d_c = d.fillna(d.apply(function))
    ddd = ddd.fillna(d_c)
    return ddd
```

If there are missing values ​​in the month, they are replaced by the values ​​obtained from the aggregation function from the 'function' argument. If there are all Nan values ​​in the month, then we calculate 'function' from all months, and if all Nan values ​​are in the year, then we calculate 'function' from the entire column.It is guaranteed that at least one value in each column is not equal to NaN.

Input and Output u can see [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12R137YDSUHcfxu6xJwjoxtlFXKwpzyXZ?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @user20423494, can you share an example (3 to 5 rows) of your initial dataframe? and also an example of what the result should be

Comment: @Luca i put dataset(and output) in to google_colab

Comment: "When solving a problem, it is forbidden to use the loop and condition operators of the Python language to process the dataframe" - why so?

Comment: @dankal444 just a limitation)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Polars (https://www.pola.rs/) to speed up the computation.

In the small test I ran with your sample data, the Pandas function took 31.3ms while the same function in Polars took 6.36ms (divide the time by 5).
For bigger data, you might see even bigger gains.

You can install polars with `pip install polars`.

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as 

# Initial Pandas dataframe
df_pandas.head(2)
        date    col0  col1  col2
0 2022-11-14  2047.0   NaN   NaN
1 2022-11-16     NaN   NaN   NaN

# Pandas function (I modify slightly what you shared based on your expected result)
def fillna_date(data, function = 'mean'):
    d = data.copy()
    #d.index = pd.to_datetime(d.index)
    d_m = d.groupby([d.date.dt.year, d.date.dt.month]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.apply(function)))
    ddd = d.fillna(d_m)
    d_y = d.groupby(d.date.dt.year).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.apply(function)))
    ddd = ddd.fillna(d_y)
    d_c = d.fillna(d.apply(function))
    ddd = ddd.fillna(d_c)
    return ddd

# Run the function with Pandas
fillna_date(df_pandas)
31.3 ms

# Convert the dataframe from Pandas to Polars
df_polars = pl.from_pandas(df_pandas)

# Run the calculation in Polars
df_polars = df_polars.with_columns(
    pl.col(column.name).fill_null(
        pl.coalesce([
            pl.mean(column.name).over(pl.col('date').dt.truncate('1mo')),
            pl.mean(column.name).over(pl.col('date').dt.year()), 
            pl.mean(column.name)
            ])
    ) 
    for column in df if column.name in ['col0','col1','col2']
)
6.36 ms

# Convert back to Pandas (if needed)
df_pandas_with_results = df_polars.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)
```

If you try the solution, I would be curious to hear about the speed-up you have on the full data

Comment: You can improve on the Pandas functions (for example removing the data.copy, but if you are looking to increase performance, then Polars is the way to go

Comment: thx, it looks impressive!!!) but u use 'for' looping, and this is prohibited by the condition. Verification takes place on a hidden dataset, so I can not say how fast it really is)this is a learning task. Actually,I already solved it)

Comment: but I think it's worth taking a closer look at this library, it will come in handy for the future, thanks!

Comment: yes, it's a comprehension list for the columns (for loop). Polars will run all columns in parallel so the for loop is just to specify the transformations to run on each column.

it's not a for loop on each row of the dataset.

anyway, good to hear that you found your solution